# filter pandas dataframe for timedeltas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I got a pandas dataframe, containing timestamps 'expiration' and 'date'.
I want to filter for rows with a certain maximum delta between expiration and date.
When doing fr.expiration - fr.date I obtain timedelta values, but don't know how 
to get a filter criteria such as fr[timedelta(fr.expiration-fr.date)<=60days]

Comment: fr.expiration-fr.date <= timedelta(days = 60) - this helps?

Comment: You should include a toy example demonstrating the issue.

Answer (score 3):

for the 60 days you're looking to compare to, create a timedelta object of that value timedelta(days=60) and use that for the filter. and if you're already getting timedelta objects from the subtraction, recasting it to a timedelta seems unnecessary.

and finally, make sure you check the signs of the timedeltas you're comparing.

Answer (score 3):

@ sashkello
Thanks,

```
filterfr = filterfr[filterfr.expiration-filterfr.date <=  numpy.timedelta64(datetime.timedelta(days = 60))]
```

did the trick.

```
filterfr.expiration-filterfr.date
```

resulted in timedelta64 values
and raised TypeError: can't compare datetime.timedelta to long.
Converting to numpy.timedelta before comparision worked.